# Copy a string to clipboard in Linux KDE Plasma

Tags: c++, linux, kde-plasma

I am doing a GUI program in C++ and I use OpenSuse with KDE Plasma. I would like to copy to clipboard a string. How can I accomplish that?
Here is my code:

```
#include <wx_pch.h>
#include <wx.msgdlg.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
void SimpleGUIFrame::CopyToClipboard(string str) 
{ 
  // copy str to cliboard
}
```

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't forget how to create a [mre] of your own attempt, or how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: I reviewed the help pages, I am totally happy with my question.  I will provide a minimal reproducible example.